# Type() function not consistent

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use the type of data in a dictionary to determine an operation.

I have a dictionary of heterogeneous types: strings, Nonetype and numpy arrays.

The code I have right now looks like this:

```
for key in pe.sources['Source 1'].keys():
    if type(pe.sources['Source 1'][key]) == 'numpy.ndarray':
        print("array: %s" %(key))
    else:
        print('attr: %s' %(key))
```

and it returns:

```
attr: TxData
attr: Trellis
attr: Encoded
attr: coding
attr: location
attr: Message
attr: Pcode
attr: gain
attr: message
attr: chemical
attr: bitrate
```

However, if I do:

```
type(pe.sources['Source 1']['TxData'])
```

it returns:

```
 numpy.ndarray
```

Why is my conditional not triggering?

Comment: The `type()` of ANYTHING can never possibly be `'numpy.ndarray'` - the function returns the type, *not* the name of the type.  Try it without those quote marks (and you may need to change the `numpy` part to `np` or however you imported the module).

Comment: There is a difference between `__str__()` and `__repr__()`...

Comment: type() doesn't return a string, it returns a type.  So check against a type.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare with a string, compare with the type itself:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(a) == 'numpy.ndarray'
False
>>> type(a) == numpy.ndarray
True
```

`str(type(a))` won't work either, because of the string you actually get:

```
>>> str(type(a))
"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"
```

Although really, unless you want *exactly* that type, usually you want `isinstance`, not `type(something) == something_else`:

```
>>> isinstance(a, numpy.ndarray)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

jasonharper's comment fixed it.

"The type() of ANYTHING can never possibly be 'numpy.ndarray' - the function returns the type, not the name of the type. Try it without those quote marks (and you may need to change the numpy part to np or however you imported the module)."

Comment: DSMs answer (recent edit) to use isinstance is a better way to perform this check. "isinstance(pe.sources['Source 1'][key], numpy.ndarray)"